# How to combine a stereo audio signal, but maintain the original stereo separation?

Tags: analog, audio, stereo

A long time ago I had a CD player boombox and wanted to add a "subwoofer" to it (it was really just a small guitar amp with the EQ set to cut the highs and mids).  The CD player had a 3.5mm line input jack that conveniently worked as a line out as well.  My naive approach was to just bridge the right and left channels together from the line in and run that to the mono input of the guitar amp.  This had the unfortunate, but obvious in hindsight, side effect of combining the signals going to the main speakers.

Is there some sort of circuit (ideally passive) that my younger self could have built to combine the signals for the "subwoofer" while maintaining the stereo separation for the main speakers?

Comment: Yes. A 10 kilohm resistor from each channel to a common point feeding the subwoofer will do this fine.

Comment: Unless the woofer has a low pass filter you can add one with a resistance from each source joined together with a shunt capacitor to block 200 Hz or RC=> 1ms.

Comment: It is possible to combine the signals for the subwoofer while maintaining stereo separation for the main speakers. But there are always trade-offs. You previously fed the sub-woofer only signal into a guitar amp. (Which I assume is separate from the amp which drives your left and right speakers) Is that still an option? To get the required isolation will either require some attenuation (which can be fixed with an amplifier) or very bulky and heavy components.